# KML Screen Overlay - works on google Earth but not on ArcGIS

Tags: kml, arcgis-online, overlay

I've been trying various things to get this to work on ArcGIS Online for the past couple of hours, but have not been able to figure it out.

It works perfectly fine on Google Earth but ArcGIS Online only shows the folder "Screen Overlay Folder" but not the image inside it.

Is there any specific syntax to use for ArcGIS Online?

[image: Screen Overlay KML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen overlays inside a KML are not currently supported in ArcGIS Online:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/kml.htm

> The current limitations of using KML layers in Map Viewer are as
>   follows:
>
> - The following elements do not display in a map: regionated KML,    view-based and time-based refresh parameters, regions inside network links, and screen overlays.

Comment: Thanks for that, would you happen to know any alternative ways of displaying an on screen (screen-fixed) logo/legend in ArcGIS online please? Preferably through an addition to the KMLs

Comment: No, sorry I don't have any thoughts. Screen overlays are typically used as a legend or supplemental text in a KML file.The ArcGIS Online viewer has its own legend component, thus one possible reason why they haven't added support for the overlay. If you have ArcMap/Pro you could possibly extract the KML to features, and republish the features to Online as a hosted service; that will allow a legend to be shown using the built in functionality.